# Convert varchar to datefield in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am aware that this is a very common and have tried using the solutions suggested on similar questions. However, I cant seem to make it work.

I have a column which contains dates, but it is of `varchar` datatype.

The data looks like this:

```
startdate
-----------
15/01/2007
29/06/1998
07/12/2001
```

and so on..

I tried the following command

```
try_convert(datetime, startdate) as 'startdate'
```

But it returns a lot of NULLs even when there is a date populated in the original column.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Those NULLS are because the values are unable to be converted a datetime. You really should be storing dates in the appropriate datatype. Storing dates as text is really common for some reason and is almost always terrible for reasons such as this.

Comment: Could you find some value that returns null?

Comment: If you're getting *`NULL`* returned, and you don't want them, i'd suggest inspecting those results. Run the following query and have a look at the return data; you'll probably quickly see why it;'s failing: `SELECT startdate FROM [YourTable] WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, startdate) IS NULL;`

Comment: I would recommend using the `datetime2(0)` datatype - try this `try_convert(datetime2(0), startdate) as 'startdate'` - does this return more "usable" values?

Answer (score 1):

The [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) method accepts three arguments: Data type, Expression, and Style.
You need to use the `Style` argument:

```
try_convert(datetime, startdate, 103) as 'startdate' -- 103 is dd/MM/yyyy
```

([a list of supported styles can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql))

Also, You should store date values as `Date`, not as `varchar`.
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)